# Can't install Gulp - is it deprecated?

Tags: wordpress, gulp

I'm new and learning to dev following a course on Udemy on WordPress. I'm fairly inexperienced at Terminal and part of the course has shifted into learning JavaScript where he is using `gulp watch` to see changes automatically updated.

Try as I might I cannot get Gulp to install on my MBP running El Capitan, I keep seeing this message about it being deprecated and to follow the info on [this link on Medium](https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5)

Problem is, being a beginner I have no idea what any of that means. I have changed directory into the root of the folder structure where I should be, and I have copied over four files as instructed (gulpfile.js, package.json, settings.js and webpack.config.js) but not matter what I try I get the following error:

```
Dans-MBP:app danmichael$ npm install gulp
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.11: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm WARN deprecated natives@1.1.3: This module relies on Node.js's internals and will break at some point. Do not use it, and update to graceful-fs@4.x.
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/danmichael/Local Sites/fictional-university/app/node_modules/gulp
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/danmichael/Local Sites/fictional-university/app/node_modules
npm WARN fictional-university-lwc@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

I have tried using 'sudo' before the install command to no avail either. Most recently (today) I am now also seeing an 'EACCES' error that I don't know how to fix, and as far as I know I AM set to Adminstrator (only user of this Mac):

```
npm ERR! path /Users/danmichael/Local Sites/fictional-university/app/node_modules/gulp
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/Users/danmichael/Local Sites/fictional-university/app/node_modules/gulp'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/Users/danmichael/Local Sites/fictional-university/app/node_modules/gulp'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/Users/danmichael/Local Sites/fictional-university/app/node_modules/gulp\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/danmichael/Local Sites/fictional-university/app/node_modules/gulp' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

If I run `node -v`, I get v8.11.1.
If I run `gulp -v`, I get CLI version 3.9.1, Local version 3.9.1

But I still can't run `gulp watch`.

Comment: (I've trimmed to make this less chatty - my advice is to ask questions succinctly and confidently. It's OK to be a beginner. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366394/472495) for some evidence that language perceived to be elevating readers to expert status may be statistically more likely to elicit a poor reaction).

Comment: If you're stuck, then you could always just install Vagrant or a virtualisation system like VirtualBox, and then do your stuff in a VM. Gulp will Just Work™ on Linux. Windows is usually harder to run open source stuff, and in my experience Macs are generally OK, but Linux is definitely easiest.

Comment: Thank you.Doesn't clarify anything with my Gulp problem though.

Comment: If you can't move from OS X, sure. But are you not able to use a VM on your Mac? It would get you moving again, and you can fix the Mac part of the problem (and dump the VM) at another time.

Comment: I did manage to get XAMPP running and can run WP from a localhost environment, I moved my files across into there and it is working, so thank you - back into it again, just with different issues now lol.